# Find the relation of quantity and price, assuming it is linear

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would I find the numbers in between if:

- 1 item = $75
- 40 items = $600

For example: What would 2 items be? 14? 26? 37? etc...

What would the formula be that is used to determine the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a linear increase, then the increase per item is going to be

$$m=\frac{\$600-\$75}{40-1} \approx \$13.46154.$$

So the total price $P$ for $n$ items with $1 \leq n \leq 40$ is $P(n) = \$75 + m(n-1).$